# Firestore deleting document using snapshot

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, angularfire2

```
 players2:Observable<String[]>;

deletePlayerFromAvailable(id:string, firstName:string, lastName:string): Observable<String[]>{



    this.matchDoc = this.afs.doc<Match>(`matches/${id}`);
    this.players2 = this.matchDoc.collection<String>('availablePlayers', ref => ref.where('firstname', '==' , firstName)).valueChanges()



    return this.players2;

  }
```

I can retrieve the data using valueChanges() method but i need the document ID of this dynamic query to delete the document from the 'availablePlayers' collection. How do i achieve this? When i start using SnapshotChanges() method the error is

```
Type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<String[]>'.
```

on this.players2

Let me know if you need any other details.

EDIT 2 
New method that retrieves a string of the doc id that i need, but method is returning no value - console is printing undefined.

```
  getPlayerFromMatchDayAvailable(player:Player, id:String):string{

  this.playerscollection = this.afs.collection<Player>(`matchdays/${id}/availablePlayers`, ref => ref.where('email','==','john@test.com'))
  this.players2 = this.playerscollection.snapshotChanges()
  this.players2.subscribe( data => {
    if(data){
      console.log(data);
      data.map(test => {
        console.log(test.payload.doc.id);
        this.af = test.payload.doc.id;

      });

    }

  })

  console.log(this.af)
  return this.af;



  //  this.players2.forEach(player => {
  //    player.forEach(playerData => {
  //      let data = playerData.payload.doc.data();
  //      let ids = playerData.payload.doc.id;
  //      this.af = playerData.payload.doc.id;
  //      console.log(id,data)

  //    });
  //  });




  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete a player from a sub collection based on its first_name property?

Comment: yes - first its matchdays(collection)->matchday(document)->availablePlayers(subcollection) 
Edit: Also idk the id of that specific document in the subcollection until i do snapshotchanges() so i am looking for help in that regard.